# Converting datetime from CSV import formatting error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have imported a CSV file using read_csv.  The raw data in the column of the CSV that I am interested in records the date in the format as follows:

```
19/01/2012  9:00:00 AM
```

However, when the data is imported it is shown as:

```
2005-03-21 10:30:00
```

Not sure why this is happening.  Ultimately I am interested in extracting the date (19/01/2012) and using this to calculate the number of days differance from the earliest date in the column.  Something along the lines of....

```
df['date_column'] = (df['date_column'] - df['date_column'].min())
```

I have tried a couple of things, firstly:

```
df['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'], dayfirst=True)
```

This returns the same date format as shown above.  Namely `2005-03-21 10:30:00`

Second attempt was to try

```
df['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'], format ='%d-%m-%y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

This gave me the error

> ValueError: time data '2004-03-16 11:40:00' does not match format '%d-%m-%y %I:%M:%S %p' (match)

I have tried a couple of minor variations to the above.  I am using Jupyter v 5.7.4 running Python 3.7.1

Certainly would appreciate any advice / help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think in `read_csv` is `date_column` column already converted to datetimes, so convert to dates is not necessary.

If subtract min values get timedeltas, with different format:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03 15:12:10', periods=10, freq='23Min')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_column': rng})  

df['diff'] = (df['date_column'] - df['date_column'].min())
```

And if neded datetime in your original format use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['date_1'] = df['date_column'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
print (df)
          date_column     diff                  date_1
0 2017-04-03 15:12:10 00:00:00  03/04/2017 15:12:10 PM
1 2017-04-03 15:35:10 00:23:00  03/04/2017 15:35:10 PM
2 2017-04-03 15:58:10 00:46:00  03/04/2017 15:58:10 PM
3 2017-04-03 16:21:10 01:09:00  03/04/2017 16:21:10 PM
4 2017-04-03 16:44:10 01:32:00  03/04/2017 16:44:10 PM
5 2017-04-03 17:07:10 01:55:00  03/04/2017 17:07:10 PM
6 2017-04-03 17:30:10 02:18:00  03/04/2017 17:30:10 PM
7 2017-04-03 17:53:10 02:41:00  03/04/2017 17:53:10 PM
8 2017-04-03 18:16:10 03:04:00  03/04/2017 18:16:10 PM
9 2017-04-03 18:39:10 03:27:00  03/04/2017 18:39:10 PM
```

Comment: The example of strftime was helpful.  But the main issue is that something is happening when I read in the data.  Date changes from 2012 to 2005.  Not sure what is going on.  But thanks for having a look at my problem.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the day-difference can only be calculated if you convert the date to a day:

```
import datetime as dt

df['date_column'] = (df['date_column'] - df['date_column'].min()).dt.days
```

Comment: Thanks for having a look at the problem.  Something still going wrong when I read in the data though.